# Как получить доступ к текстовой строке поиска в ActionBar

Tags: android, android-search-view

Добавляю в ActionBar элемент поиска следующим образом:

```
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    }
```

Ставлю обработчик - тут все нормально работает (детали можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161499/how-can-i-get-the-text-entered-in-search-in-action-bar-to-a-string)).

Но дальше в коде (в другом методе), мне надо получить доступ к этой строке ввода, для того, чтобы поставить туда свое значение ... не могу понять, как это сделать?

**upd:** 
Можно сделать поле внутри класса `SearchView searchView` и используя поле, управлять текстом поиска из любого метода `searchView.setQuery("", false);`.

Но, хотелось бы найти способ, получить доступ к SearchView не создавая поля.

Comment: сделайте эту строку полем класса и она будет доступна во всех методах класса

Comment: Этот способ я понимаю. Но не хотелось бы выносить это в поле, так как это класс Activity и потом придется думать о сохранении значении этого поля ... хотелось бы получить доступ к тексту через существующие объекты

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.action_search);
if(searchView!=null){
    searchView.setQuery("foo",false);
}
```

Недостатки данного метода:

- тяжелый поиск по всему дереву view (можно искать в toolbar'е)
- в onCreate activity его не будет
- в зависимости от значения showAsAction его просто может не быть.

Поэтому лучше кэшировать в onCreateOptionsMenu в свойство activity.

Comment: Спасибо! Решил все же searchView сделать полем класса.